# How to prepare for freelancing?

Tags: consulting

I am about to finish my Graduation ( B.Tech - Computer Science) very soon. I do like the idea of working with freedom like freelancing provides. Honestly, I noticed quite a significant difference in what we learn at an undergraduate level and the expectations and demands of clients over at freelancer.

What I am trying to say is, although I have written programs in C/C++/C# but the level of programming was never of that stature. We did normal programs, implemented some algorithms at best but freelancing looks way above my level right now.

How exactly do I prepare myself to become a reputed freelancer.

What things do I have to focus on for a career in Computer Science, Programming? Obviously, hard work is necessary but what about the mindset and planning to achieve something as big as this? Please share you experience and point me in the right direction.

Comment: edited the generic title to something related to the question. Also, this question has been asked many many times before. Did you search for previous questions?

Comment: You may also want to add some specifics to your question, such as what type of work you would like to do as freelancer and which country or region you are located. So your first lesson as freelancer: clear and precise communication (and that really is something you need to learn as a freelancer, I'm not  flaming)

Comment: I mentioned programming languages . It was quite obvious I would love to work in IT, computer science. Although the question is general, I was looking for a motivational story/ experience which they would love to share.

Comment: I think this is merely too broad. The general plan.. pay down debt, save money, get necessary software/hardware, find clients. That's pretty much the same for any freelancer.

Answer (score 6):

I've got 20+ years consulting within IT behind me so I would hope that counts for something. Hopefully a prior answer I supplied might help:
https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/8576/how-to-build-a-startup-freelance-software-qa-in-the-us/8585#8585

I recommend getting a year or two in a full time job first. Anyone can work in a bar or restaurant, but the best make the biggest tips. If the food and drink being served stays the same, and the location is the same, the ability to provide good customer service will be the key difference. So... while you might think you can code, successful consulting means you need to know how to sell yourself, regularly, you need know how to work well with others in stressful possibly politically unfriendly situations. College/school teaches you lots - I respect what you have attained so far, but you will have to learn and adapt new environments and new skills every day for the rest of your life.

Best of luck

Comment: If you work for a large company, there are hogh chances that you will work on some feature from the very narrow field, and you will earn nothing. Guys of 5+ such experience wanted to shoot themselves when they started doing apps as freelancers.

Answer (score 4):

Freelancing is a big leap when you decide to take it. You have to remember that as a new graduate you don't have much "real world" experience. My suggestion is to start out working in a professional capacity with a company, to build up your CV. Once you have worked for a year or so, then start trying to find freelance work in your spare time. This will help build up your reputation as a freelancer. The last thing you want is to quit your job and have no income coming in. With no reputation as a freelancer people will be more likely to pick those who have experience and a good reputation. You will find over time that you will be able to have your own clients and even business maybe. 
Also, keep in mind that when freelancing there are many risks in the way of how you will get paid and if you get paid. You have to screen your clients and learn how to pick the best ones because some will not be honest unfortunately. You also risk having little or no pay during slow times. 
You also have to decide if you want to be on a site such as UpWork or People Per Hour, or if you want to stay more local and advertise your work in your neighborhood. I hope this all helps and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently hire contractors, so I'll share how I select applicants. I think that's how most other contractors hire a contractor.

It's not a good idea to offer a low rate just because you think you are a fresh graduate. You'll only get cheap and dumb projects. You wouldn't be able to develop your history, and you wouldn't be able to develop your talent as well. Trust me, anybody who wants to pay you low have very little respect to you, and you wouldn't want to work with them (why waste your career?).

You have to be **good** in something practical. What do you want to do? If you want to do iOS apps, you should read/study Objective-C/Swift etc. You'll have to prove you are a great iOS app developer by doing some apps under your name.

When I post a job advertisement, I'd filter anybody who doesn't give a CV in the application. I'd also filtered out anybody who has never worked full-time. I'd put strong preference on whoever has a project developed under her name. For example, if I'm looking for an iOS app developer, I'd expect someone who have an app on the App Store. I'd also always check the candidate on Linkedln and the company the application works. I'd be expecting a positive profile.

What does that mean for you?

- Get a full-time job to grow your CV and your technical skills. You should try to work at somewhere that you want to work and enjoy. If you enjor your work, you'll be able to transfer what you learn to freelancing.
- Start your own project or join an open-source. Your want your name searchable on Google.